# Why i got 'undefined' when function contructer called with already existed object?

Tags: javascript

**Here is my CODE in snippet .**

Also tell me what is happening under the hood of javascript engine when i called this CODE

```js
    function foo(a){
        
        this.a = a;
        
    }

    var obj0 ={
       
        foo:foo
    };

    var obj1 ={
        
        foo:foo
    };

    console.log( obj0.foo(5) );  // undefined
    console.log( obj1.foo(10) ); // undefined
```

Comment: don't downvote if you don't know answer

Comment: what does foo `return`?

Comment: foo return variable a = (whatever i passed) to object

Comment: @Meet Patel are you sure?

Comment: I don't see any return statement in `foo`.

Comment: You need to return out of `foo()` --> `return this.a`

Comment: Check `obj0.a`. @DarrenSweeney why?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The question is why is the OP getting undefined, that's why - yes, he can get the value in different ways but that's not the question

Comment: @DarrenSweeney OP has made a bad question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That maybe so, but just trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Well it returns `undefined` because there's no return statement in

```
function foo(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
```

When you call `console.log(obj.foo(5))` you don't instantiate a new foo object using `foo` as a constructor function, you simply call `foo` as a regular function (here as a method of `obj`).

However, if you'd had instantiated an object you'd have used : `console.log(new obj.foo(5))`.

Calling `foo` on `obj0` with `1` as its parameter simply sets `obj0`'s property `a` to `1` and nothing more. However if you wanted something to be returned you'd have written :

```
function foo(a) {
  this.a=a;
  return /*something here*/;
}
```

EDIT 
You say that you call the constructor function on an already existing object, that is technically true : you call the function but not as a constructor function. A constructor function is called as a constructor function with the `new` keyword and then, and only then, will return a new object.

What you're actually doing is just using `foo` as a setter for `a` on those objects (and there's no return statement, so it returns undefined).

Comment: `obj0` is already an object. Why does the OP need to use the new keyword?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The OP seems to expect that `foo` is being called as a constructor function, but they forgot to use `new`

Comment: obj0 is an object but you don't have a return statement. If you use `obj.foo(1)` and then `console.log(obj)` you'll see that obj has a property `a` that has its value to `1`

Comment: There is no return statement so don't expect it to return anything besides `undefined `